# Why opening file from internet takes so long in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, internet

This was bothering me for a quite time.

I.e. when I'm opening an `Readme.md` file in [Typora](https://typora.io/) (or any other other application that uses native Windows file explorer) located in internet, it takes much longer (several seconds) than the file from the disk (~2 seconds), even though they're the same files.

[image]

File size should not be a big factor here. File is pretty small and my internet connection solid.

Why does it take so long? It happens **only** when opening file from the internet. (haven't tested local network though)

This affect any Windows NT system.

Comment: It is pretty obvious that it takes a bit of time to load something from the internet onto your computer.

Comment: Are you really using Windows NT? In 2018???

Comment: @MichaelBay: All Windows versions since then (including 2000, XP, Vista, 7, 8, 10) are NT series.

Comment: @grawity Sure, but what's the point of posting that instead of the actual version(s)? To say that they aren't using Windows 95, 98 or ME?

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes:

2. Windows' *WebClient* is actually a WebDAV client, not plain HTTP, so it makes a few additional requests – two `OPTIONS`, two `PROPFIND`, with no connection reuse in sight. So you're looking at ~5 TLS handshakes and HTTP requests just for a single file.
3. In some cases (I couldn't figure out when), Windows tries *all* its clients to retrieve the file – before WebDAV it attempts SMB, which can have a long delay if the SMB ports are blocked.

Comment: Thats interesting. I'll check with fiddler what kind of requests are being made.